# Cant download image off pixiv with scraper Python 3 selenium beautifulsoup4 urllib.request

Tags: python-3.x, image, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to download images off https://www.pixiv.net/, so it was a little troublesome. Had to log in to even begin scraping details off pages. When I tried to urllib.request.urlretrieve them I get a 403 forbidden error. I searched the web for other methods but they always end up with a 403 forbidden error

Here's a sample of the page i want to scrape,
https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=71751889

To even begin scraping, one would have to log in, you wouldn't be able to find the necessary elements without logging in.

```
import requests
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def login(browser):
    Log_In = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Login')
    Log_In.click()
    Username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='LoginComponent']/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
    Username.send_keys('') #input username
    Password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='LoginComponent']/form/div[1]/div[2]/input")
    Password.send_keys('') #input password
    Login = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[1]
    time.sleep(1)
    Login.click()


def search(browser):
    time.sleep(1)
    searchbox = browser.find_element_by_id('suggest-input')
    searchbox.send_keys('toyosatomimi no miko')
    searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    image = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_25taFA4')
    image.click()


def get_soup(browser):
    return BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')

def download_image(soup, file_path):
    url = soup.find_all('a', {'target': '_blank'})[1].get('href')
    file_name = 'image'
    full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_path)

url = "https://www.pixiv.net/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
login(browser)
search(browser)
soup = get_soup(browser)
browser.get(url)
soup = get_soup(browser)
download_image(soup, 'D:\\instagram_photos')


Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/pixiv scraper/venv/pixiv scrape.py", line 95, in <module>
    download_image(soup, 'D:\\instagram_photos')
  File "D:/pixiv scraper/venv/pixiv scrape.py", line 57, in download_image
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_path)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
    32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
    32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

This is my code, i wonder if anyone can help?

Comment: Check out https://pypi.org/project/wget/  This is what I use when I am downloading images from the web. Just call it and pass the absolute link for the image that you're trying to get.

Comment: i tried it out, 403 error again. I think the site is blocking downloads of images, just have to automate save as image i guess.

Answer (score 0):

`.urlretrieve()` has no cookies or session like in selenium browser that why you got 403, and you also need to set user-agent.

```
def download_image(browser, file_path):
    userAgent = browser.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
    seleniumCookies= browser.get_cookies()
    cookies = ''
    for cookie in seleniumCookies:
        cookies += '%s=%s;' % (cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', userAgent)]
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookies))

    soup = get_soup(browser)
    url = soup.find_all('a', {'target': '_blank'})[1].get('href')
    file_name = 'image'
    full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_path)

url = "https://www.pixiv.net/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
login(browser)
search(browser)
# you may need to WebDriverWait until search result appear
download_image(browser, 'D:\\instagram_photos')
```